# How to add subdomain for a nodejs+expressjs application?

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

In my nodejs application I need to add subdomains dynamically. My application contains a list of books. If a user login to my site and goes to one of the book's details page , the url should change , so that the url should contain the bookname as the subdomain.  This should happen for each details page.
Can anyone help me to do this in localhost ?

Versions:
node : v0.10.22
express : 4.12.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems to consider:

- direct requests from any subdomain to your server
- determine what the actual subdomain given to the request is, and react accordingly

For the first part, configuring your [nginx](http://nginx.org/) / entry point of your server should be enough and straight forward.

For the second part, you need to be able to determine the given subdomain in a middleware. [Express.js actually has something for that](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.subdomains), allowing you to write a middleware to handle that:

```
// ... app creation and other middlewares

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var requestedSubdomain = req.subdomains.join('.');

  // Do something with it, e.g.:
  return database.getResourceWithName(requestedSubdomain, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
      return next(err);

    req.resource = result;
    // Now all subsequent middleware will have access to the resource via `req.resource`
    return next();
  });
});

// ... other middlewares and route definitions, then `app.listen()`
```

Note that, in this specific case, I decided to join the subdomains together to build the resource name, but you may have to adapt it to your situation.

I hope it helps!